# LandScape/Portrait size differ iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, landscape, landscape-portrait

I have five `UIButton` and I need to set the frame of the `UIButton`  in such a way that it should be for the `Landscape` and `portrait` different size. 
but the from the Below code `viewDidLoad` its loading fine but problem is that After loading the stack When I move to the `Landscape` to  `portrait` or the   `portrait` to `Landscape` it should be change according to the `viewdidload` size which i have set ..but this is not happening...its been overlapping as previous Button is already created....what changes do i require so that when change the view ..button should come properly ..should not be overlap.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
 int Height = 200;
    int Yposition = 20;
    for (int k=0; k<5; k++)
    {
 if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation  == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

        UIButton *loPlayButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [loPlayButton addTarget:self action:@selector(PlayButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            //   loPlayButton.tag  = 100+k;
        NSLog(@"tag is %i",loPlayButton.tag);
        loPlayButton.alpha = 1.0;

        UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"vid.png"];
        [loPlayButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        loPlayButton.frame=CGRectMake(520, Yposition +(k*Height +170), image.size.width, 30);
        // loPlayButton.tag=3;


        [mScrollView_por addSubview:loPlayButton];
        [mPlayButtonsArray addObject:loPlayButton];
             }



        if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {


            UIButton *loPlayButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [loPlayButton addTarget:self action:@selector(PlayButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                //   loPlayButton.tag  = 100+k;
            NSLog(@"tag is %i",loPlayButton.tag);
            loPlayButton.alpha = 1.0;

            UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"vid.png"];
            [loPlayButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            loPlayButton.frame=CGRectMake(440, Yposition +(k*Height +170), image.size.width, 30);
                // loPlayButton.tag=3;


            [mScrollView_por addSubview:loPlayButton];
            [mPlayButtonsArray addObject:loPlayButton];

        }}}


- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

 [self viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation statusBarOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(statusBarOrientation))
    {
        [self ArrangeControllsFor_Protrate];
    }
    else
    {
        [self ArrangeControllsFor_LandScape];
    }
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations

    switch (interfaceOrientation) {

        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            //[self ArrangeControllsFor_Protrate];
            [self performSelector:@selector(ArrangeControllsFor_Protrate) withObject:Nil afterDelay:0.005f];
            return YES;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            [self performSelector:@selector(ArrangeControllsFor_LandScape) withObject:Nil afterDelay:0.005f];
            return YES;
            break;
    }
}
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    //switch ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) {
    switch (toInterfaceOrientation) {

        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            //[self ArrangeControllsFor_Protrate];
            [self performSelector:@selector(ArrangeControllsFor_Protrate) withObject:Nil afterDelay:0.005f];
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            [self performSelector:@selector(ArrangeControllsFor_LandScape) withObject:Nil afterDelay:0.005f];
            break;
    }
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
-(void)ArrangeControllsFor_Protrate
{set frames here.
}
-(void)ArrangeControllsFor_LandScape
{set frames here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mate add the your rotation code in separate method and call it from viewDidLoad and when it changes the orientation. Like in the below code :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [self rotateTheView];
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation     duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

     [self rotateTheView];
}

- (void) rotateTheView{
    int Height = 200;
    int Yposition = 20;
    for (int k=0; k<5; k++)
    {
      if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation  == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

          UIButton *loPlayButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
          [loPlayButton addTarget:self action:@selector(PlayButtonAction:)        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
          //   loPlayButton.tag  = 100+k;
          NSLog(@"tag is %i",loPlayButton.tag);
          loPlayButton.alpha = 1.0;

         UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"vid.png"];
        [loPlayButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         loPlayButton.frame=CGRectMake(520, Yposition +(k*Height +170), image.size.width, 30);
        // loPlayButton.tag=3;


        [mScrollView_por addSubview:loPlayButton];
        [mPlayButtonsArray addObject:loPlayButton];
    }



    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {


        UIButton *loPlayButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [loPlayButton addTarget:self action:@selector(PlayButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            //   loPlayButton.tag  = 100+k;
        NSLog(@"tag is %i",loPlayButton.tag);
        loPlayButton.alpha = 1.0;

        UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"vid.png"];
        [loPlayButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        loPlayButton.frame=CGRectMake(440, Yposition +(k*Height +170), image.size.width, 30);
            // loPlayButton.tag=3;


        [mScrollView_por addSubview:loPlayButton];
        [mPlayButtonsArray addObject:loPlayButton];

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to call **viewDidLoad** manually. Do not do that.

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {

  [self resetFrame:[[UIApplication sharedApplication]statusBarOrientation]]; 

}

  - (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
 {
  [self resetFrame:toInterfaceOrientation];
 }


- (void) resetFrame: (UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{


if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation))
{
   // For portrait

}
else
{

    // for landscape

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need remove all UIButton before adding the new 5 UIButton from your scroll.

```
for (UIView *button in mScrollView_por.subviews) {
    if([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        [button removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: it throws a error...no visible @interface for UIView declares the selector iskindof]

Comment: Is [button isKindOfClass:...]