# Orientation in iPhone-4 and iPhone-5 differs (iOS 7.0 and XCODE 5.0)

Tags: ios, ios7, orientation

Before you could mark my question as duplicate or vote down please read the question carefully.

I wanted to make my app compatible for both landscape and portrait mode.

**Brief idea about the app : I have a table and i navigate to another view on click of its row**

i came across this link :

[I used the accepted answer on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112487/landscape-portrait-size-differ-ios?rq=1)

Problem 1 : Initially if i load the app in landscape mode the table appears to be in the left corner.That is it does not changes its frame.

Problem 2 : If i load the app in Portrait mode and then switch to landscape mode then it works great, **BUT** when i click a row -> navigate to another view -> and again i pop from that view to come to table view, the table again appears to be in the left side corner, similar to problem one.

**What I Tried :**

1) I tried to check the code for orientation in viewDidLoad instead of viewWillAppear : No change

2) I tried to check the code for orientation in viewDidAppear instead of viewWillAppear :The table frame change and both the problems is solved but it takes a while for the table to change frame. That is , it still appears on the left corner,shrinked, and after say 1-2 seconds it expands to appear what we want.

***What I Think : Is there a problem in writing the code (to check orientation) in viewWillAppear ??***

To your surprise the same code is working good for iPhone 4. Only giving problem for iPhone5

Here is what my code looks like :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    UIInterfaceOrientation statusBarOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(statusBarOrientation))
    {
        [self ArrangeControllsFor_Protrate];
    }
    else
    {
        [self ArrangeControllsFor_LandScape];
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations

    switch (interfaceOrientation) {

        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            //[self ArrangeControllsFor_Protrate];
            [self performSelector:@selector(ArrangeControllsFor_Protrate) withObject:Nil afterDelay:0.005f];
            return YES;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            [self performSelector:@selector(ArrangeControllsFor_LandScape) withObject:Nil afterDelay:0.005f];
            return YES;
            break;
    }
}


- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    //switch ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) {
    switch (toInterfaceOrientation) {

        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            //[self ArrangeControllsFor_Protrate];
            [self performSelector:@selector(ArrangeControllsFor_Protrate) withObject:Nil afterDelay:0.005f];
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            [self performSelector:@selector(ArrangeControllsFor_LandScape) withObject:Nil afterDelay:0.005f];
            break;
    }
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
-(void)ArrangeControllsFor_Protrate
{
    NSLog(@"Portrait Mode");

    if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568) {


    }
    else {
        // Table genera is table and image gener is image.
        [self.tableGener setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 418)];
        [self.imageGener setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    }


}

-(void)ArrangeControllsFor_LandScape
{
    if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568) {

    [self.tableGener setFrame:CGRectMake(30, 43, 506, 310)];
    [self.imageGener setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 568, 320)];

    }
    else {

        [self.tableGener setFrame:CGRectMake(30, 43, 418, 300)];
        [self.imageGener setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
    }

}
```

Comment: instead of -(void)viewWillAppear try - (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews

Comment: @peko : You want me to write the code for orientation in (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews rather than -(void)viewWillAppear

Comment: Use AutoLayout. It will reduce your headache.

Comment: @peko :Even that is Not working

Comment: I did tick the Autolayout part !!  @brianLikeApple

Comment: How do you add tableView to IB? By Code? Or drag it to IB? Make sure you have enough constraints to its edges.

Comment: @brianLikeApple : i have an xib …i don't add it programmatically